# Cannot find symbol println

Tags: java, joptionpane, println

I just started a new java project today, and I'm having a problem with println.  Here's my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringNumGuards = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How any guards do you have?");
    int numGuards = Integer.parseInt(stringNumGuards);
    Controller headGuard = new Controller();
    System.out.println("You have ", numGuards, " guards");
} //main
```

The javac output

```
Controller.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method println(java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String)
location: class java.io.PrintStream
        System.out.println("You have ", numGuards, " guards");
```

What did I do wrong?  I've never had problems with println before.

Comment: Replace the commas with + signs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You concatenate Strings with `+` not `,`

```
System.out.println("You have ", numGuards, " guards");
```

Should become

```
System.out.println("You have " + numGuards + " guards");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have your println like this:

```
System.out.println("You have " + numGuards + " guards");
```

This concatenates a string with a variable that you put in the println statement.

Answer (score 0):

In java, you have to give `+` symbol instead of `,` in the `println` method to concatenate the strings. So you have to enter like this.

```
System.out.println("You have " + numGuards + " gurads");
```